# Why do these swap functions behave differently?

Tags: c, pointers, swap

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap1(int a, int b)
{
    int temp = a;

    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void swap2(int *a, int *b)
{
    int *temp = a;

    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void swap3(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;

    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

main()
{
    int a = 9, b = 4;

    printf("%d , %d\n", a, b);
    swap1(a, b);
    printf("%d , %d\n", a, b);
    swap2(&a, &b);
    printf("%d , %d\n", a, b);
    swap3(&a, &b);
    printf("%d , %d\n", a, b);

}
```

Comment: use < pre > and </ pre > tags

Comment: There isn't a question here, or any text whatsoever other than the title.

Comment: Maybe he just wants some help formatting it from the folks here at FormatOverflow?

Answer (score 4):

C has *value semantics* for function parameters. This means the `a` and `b` for all your three swap variants are *local variables* of the respective functions. They are *copies* of the values you pass as arguments. In other words:

- `swap1` exchanges values of two local integer variables - no visible effect outside the function
- `swap2` exchanges values of two local variables, which are pointers in this case, - same, no visible effect
- `swap3` finally gets it right and exchanges the values *pointed to* by local pointer variables.

Answer (score 2):

You're `swap2` function has no effect.

You are passing in two pointers. Inside the function, the (parameter) variables `a` and `b` are local to the function. The `swap2` function just swaps the values of these local variables around - having no effect outside the function itself.

As Anon pointed out, `swap1` has the same problem - you're just modifying local variables.

Comment: Incidentally, neither does `swap1`.

Answer (score 0):

`swap1` will not work because the function just copied the arguments, not affecting the variables in `main`.

`swap2` will not work either.

Comment: That's fine as far as it goes for C++, but C does not have references.

Comment: woops. Didn't notice the `c` tag. Sorry, :o

Answer (score 0):

`swap1()` and `swap2()` have an effect limited to the scope of the function itself: the variables they swap are parameters passed by copy, and any change applied to them does not impact the source variable of your `main()` that were copied during the function call.

`swap3` works as it acts on the values **pointed by** the parameters, instead of acting on the parameters themselves. It is the only of the three that chage the value located at the memory adress in which your `main()`'s `a` and `b` variables are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, exchange values without the use of a temporary variable

```
x = x ^ y
y = x ^ y
x = x ^ y
```