# Why does this code not swap the numbers?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do these swap functions behave differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330929/why-do-these-swap-functions-behave-differently)

Have a look at the code below, aimed to swap two numbers, but it does not. Please help me to understand the reason why it does not. I am new to programming, so I would be grateful if you explain the things more than usual.
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap (int a, int b);
int main (void)
{
   int x = 1;
   int y = 2;
   swap (x, y);
   printf ("Now x is %d and y is %d\n", x, y);

   return 0;

}
//function definition of swap
void swap (int a, int b)
{
   int temp = a;
   int a = b;
   int b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Please **read a good book about *C programming*** because we cannot teach you C in a few minutes. Short answer: `swap` should take pointer arguments, and you should call it as `swap(&x, &y)`

Comment: Please read a comprehensive C language tutorial/reference. This is way too basic to be asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: @H2CO3: there is no rule saying that basic question should not be asked. Actually, [they probably should be](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C is pass-by-value, so the `swap` function receives copies of the values, and cannot affect the variables in the caller.

To affect the variables in the caller, you need to pass pointers to them.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

and call it

```
swap(&x, &y);
```

in `main`.

Comment: why calling swap(x,y) also works in c++ compilers ? I am using codeblocks 13.

Comment: Not sure which `swap` you mean. For the one in the answer, C++ has pointers too, with the same syntax as C, so it's normal. C++ also has `std::swap`, which takes references, so if you call `swap(x,y)` with a `using namespace std;` declaration before it, you call `std::swap` if you have no declaration `void swap(int a, int b);` before the call. But without the exact code, I can only guess which situation you have.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Fischer. your comment did help me. I was using `using namespace std;` and also had a `swap(int * a, int * b)` definition of mine. Apparently I was calling the `std::swap` and was expecting my own definition of swap to be called.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you pass variables by copy and not by pointer. In other words, your `swap()` functions receives its own private copies of `x` and `y` and swap them and the result of swap is not visible by the caller. The correct code might look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b);

int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    swap(&x, &y);
    printf("Now x is %d and y is %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}

//function definition of swap
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```