# Swapping Pointers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, swap, bubble-sort

My goal is to sort an array of vectors in polar form by their magnitudes. I have achieved this using a bubble sort, swapping all values within the PolarVectors one by one:

```
- (void) sortVectorsByMagnitude: (PolarVector*)one and:(PolarVector*)two
{
if (one.magnitude < two.magnitude)
    {
    PolarVector *temp = [[PolarVector alloc] init];
    temp.magnitude = one.magnitude;
    temp.angle = one.angle;
    one.magnitude = two.magnitude;
    one.angle = two.angle;
    two.magnitude = temp.magnitude;
    two.angle = temp.angle;
    }
}
```

This works but seems messy and long winded. I have tried the following code with no success. From what I understand I am swapping pointers local to this function rather than my main vector pointers.

```
- (void) sortVectorsByMagnitude: (PolarVector*)one and:(PolarVector*)two
{
    if (one.magnitude < two.magnitude)
    {
        PolarVector *temp = [[PolarVector alloc] init];
        temp = one;
        one = two;
        two = temp;
     }
}
```

I tried implementing this solution [Swapping pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180365/swapping-pointers) as follows:

```
- (void) sortVectorsByMagnitude: (PolarVector*)one and:(PolarVector*)two
{
    if (one.magnitude < two.magnitude)
    {
        PolarVector temp;
        temp = *one;
        *one = *two;
        *two = temp;
    }
}
```

This gives errors:

```
PolarVector temp  "Interface type cannot be statically allocated"

temp = *one;      "Assigning to 'PolarVector *' from incompatible type 'PolarVector'

*two = temp;      "Assigning to 'PolarVector' from incompatible type 'PolarVector *'
```

Many thanks (I hope this isn't a duplicate — I couldn't find anything directly about Objective C)

Comment: Do you need the result of the swap to be visible to the caller of `sortVectorByMagnitude:and:`?

Comment: This is pure wasted motion: ` = [[PolarVector alloc] init];`.  If you're going to assign a value to your temp pointer in the next line there's no point in creating a new object you will simply drop on the floor.

Comment: The point you're missing is that, while your second code segment is sort of doing the right thing (other than the bogus alloc/init) the updated values are never reflected back to the caller.

Comment: rmaddy: Yes the results need to be visible to the caller.

Comment: Hot Licks: Yes, very true. I guess I am going about this completely the wrong way.

Comment: @EdRutterAudioNutter Of course the simple solution in H2CO3's answer is an easy way to solve this. To fix what you have you need to change the `one` and `two` parameters to be `PolarVector **`, then use option 2 but change `temp` to be a `PolarVector *`. And be sure to change how you call `sortVectorsByMagnitude:and:` to reflect the double pointers.

Answer (score 3):

> My goal is to sort an array of vectors in polar form by their magnitudes

Then:

```
NSMutableArray *vectors = /// whatever

[vectors sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id _1, id _2) {
    PolarVector *p1 = _1, *p2 = _2;
    return p1.magnitude < p2.magnitude ? -1 :
           p1.magnitude > p2.magnitude ? +1 :
           0;
}];
```

And suddenly no need to mess around with bubble sort, manual swapping and stuff.

Comment: Can't you just say `^NSComparisonResult(PolarVector *p1, PolarVector *p2)`?

Comment: @JesseRusak I can say it, but if I write it as such, then it won't compile.

Comment: It compiles fine and produces no warnings for me (in Xcode 5).

Comment: @JesseRusak That's good news; then clearly there have been changes regarding this in Objective-C. I don't like the mandatory `id` either, but last time I checked it, compatible block types (i. e. signatures) were mandatory.

Comment: They still are mandatory, but the definition of "compatible" has been expanded, thankfully, to allow you to use a more-specific type instead of `id`.